# How to create new token (Current URL) of the product by plugin in nopcommerce 4.2?

Tags: plugins, token, nopcommerce

How to create **new token** for the **current url** of the **product** through the **plugin** in **nopcommerce 4.2**? I have create this method type of method but dont know how to call this method by plugin. Here is the method,

```
public override void AddOrderTokens(IList<Token> tokens, Order order, int languageId)
{
    string orderNotesHtml = BuildOrderNotesHtml(order, languageId);
    tokens.Add(new Token("Order.OrderNotes", orderNotesHtml, true));

    base.AddOrderTokens(tokens, order, languageId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit **MessageTokenProvider** class of the Nop.Services at your plugin then override the method as you already did. Then you have to register dependency **MessageTokenProvider** by your plugin class.

Bellow is the link code

```
builder.RegisterType<YourPluginCustomMessageTokenProvider>().As<MessageTokenProvider, IMessageTokenProvider>().InstancePerDependency();
```

You also need to increase the **Order** property of the DependencyRegistrar of your plugin.

```
public int Order => 110;
```